# How to get the key and value from map and perform certain operation on each key and value using Java8 methods

Tags: java, collections, java-8

How to get the key and value from map and perform certain operation on each key and value using Java8 methods

I got some methods but it helps only to print the message(using System.out.println),but I want to perform some operations(finding duplicates in value,comparing values using casting etc.,) in each key/value pair

Map<String,String> l_map=new TreeMap<String,String>();

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check out [`forEach()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#forEach-java.util.function.BiConsumer-).

Comment: For those operations, you can use Streams in java to find duplicates and other operations. Streams have tons of feature to make it easy.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the forEach() function of the map, and get a key and value during each iteration by using a lambda expression.

```
Map<String,String> l_map=new TreeMap<String,String>();
    l_map.forEach( (key, value) -> {
        key="";
        value="";
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Oldschool approach could be to use the method `Map.entrySet()` that returns a `Set<Map.Entry<K,V>>` (set of key-value pairs) where you can access data with `Map.Entry<K,V>.getKey()` and `Map.Entry<K,V>.getValue()`)